# C# expecting brackets when none needed and other errors I can't seem to find solution to

Tags: c#, file, debugging, error-handling

I'm making Class that will read json data from files, but for some unknown reason, I keeep geting errors. I really hope it's not only stupid mistake on my side.

**My Code: - Not working**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Blackjack
{
    class LeaderBoard
    {
        LeaderBoard(string fileName)
        {
            public string filename = fileName;
            if (!File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                File.Create(fileName);
            }
            private string contents = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
        }
    }
}
```

**My Code - Working**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Blackjack
{
    class LeaderBoard
    {
        LeaderBoard(string fileName)
        {
           
            if (!File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                File.Create(fileName);
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: Blackjack, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>C:\Users\ASUS\RiderProjects\Blackjack\Blackjack\Leaderboard.cs(13,10,13,10): error CS1513: } expected
1>C:\Users\ASUS\RiderProjects\Blackjack\Blackjack\Leaderboard.cs(15,13,15,15): error CS1519: Invalid token 'if' in class, record, struct, or interface member declaration
1>C:\Users\ASUS\RiderProjects\Blackjack\Blackjack\Leaderboard.cs(15,17,15,18): error CS1031: Type expected
1>C:\Users\ASUS\RiderProjects\Blackjack\Blackjack\Leaderboard.cs(15,17,15,18): error CS8124: Tuple must contain at least two elements.
1>C:\Users\ASUS\RiderProjects\Blackjack\Blackjack\Leaderboard.cs(15,17,15,18): error CS1026: ) expected
1>C:\Users\ASUS\RiderProjects\Blackjack\Blackjack\Leaderboard.cs(15,17,15,18): error CS1519: Invalid token '!' in class, record, struct, or interface member declaration
1>C:\Users\ASUS\RiderProjects\Blackjack\Blackjack\Leaderboard.cs(15,29,15,30): error CS1519: Invalid token '(' in class, record, struct, or interface member declaration
1>C:\Users\ASUS\RiderProjects\Blackjack\Blackjack\Leaderboard.cs(15,38,15,39): error CS8124: Tuple must contain at least two elements.
1>C:\Users\ASUS\RiderProjects\Blackjack\Blackjack\Leaderboard.cs(15,39,15,40): error CS1519: Invalid token ')' in class, record, struct, or interface member declaration
1>C:\Users\ASUS\RiderProjects\Blackjack\Blackjack\Leaderboard.cs(17,28,17,29): error CS1519: Invalid token '(' in class, record, struct, or interface member declaration
1>C:\Users\ASUS\RiderProjects\Blackjack\Blackjack\Leaderboard.cs(17,37,17,38): error CS8124: Tuple must contain at least two elements.
1>C:\Users\ASUS\RiderProjects\Blackjack\Blackjack\Leaderboard.cs(17,38,17,39): error CS1519: Invalid token ';' in class, record, struct, or interface member declaration
1>C:\Users\ASUS\RiderProjects\Blackjack\Blackjack\Leaderboard.cs(21,5,21,6): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
1>C:\Users\ASUS\RiderProjects\Blackjack\Blackjack\Leaderboard.cs(22,1,22,2): error CS1022: Type or namespace definition, or end-of-file expected
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I really don't know what is wrong... where is that missing semicolon?

Comment: maybe https://dotnetfiddle.net/V0jsZI

Comment: Thanks much! I didn't realise, that `File.ReadAllText` will not output string

Comment: Yeah (among other things) you had `ReadAllLines` which outputs a string array `ReadAllText` outputs a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use access modifiers inside a class member, they can only be applied to the class members themselves:

```
class LeaderBoard
{
    public string filename;
    private string[] contents;

    LeaderBoard(string fileName)
    {
        filename = fileName;
        if (!File.Exists(fileName))
        {
            File.Create(fileName);
        }
        contents = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you are using public and private in the constructer of your class. Also you should define the contents as a string array.

```
namespace Blackjack
{
    class LeaderBoard
    {
        LeaderBoard(string fileName)
        {
            string filename = fileName;
            if (!File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                File.Create(fileName);
            }
            string[] contents = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Blackjack
{
    class LeaderBoard
    {
        public string LeaderBoard(string fileName)
        {
            string fileContent;
            if (!File.Exists(fileName))
            {
                File.Create(fileName);
            }
            using (var sr = new StreamReader(fileName)) {
                if(sr.ReadToEnd() == null) {
                    return "File is empty";
                }
                fileContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
            return fileContent;
        }
    }
}
```

Editted, may be a bit better.

Try this :)

Comment: Using `FileInfo` to check for length and `StreamReader` is verbose and redundant to the Extreme :) see what i did there?